# Issues while handling OnPageIndexChanging and OnRowCommand C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, aspxgridview

I have a GridView which contains `OnPageIndexChanging` and `OnRowCommand`. I got an issue while I tried to paginate, it will be fired directly to the `OnRowCommand` instead of firing `OnPageIndexChanging`, It works while I remove the `OnRowCommand` but I also need the `OnRowCommand` as I have to show another grid based on this one.

GridView looks like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdJobs" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" OnPageIndexChanging="grdJobs_GridPaging" OnPageIndexChanged="btnRefresh_Click" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="JobId,JobTypeId1,JobStateId" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" OnRowCommand="grdJobs_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="grdJobs_RowDataBound" OnSorting="grdJobs_Sorting" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdJobs_SelectedIndexChanged" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="JobId">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblJobId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("JobId") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblJobId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("JobId") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerName" HeaderText="Client" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Task" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TaskId" SortExpression="TaskId" Visible="False">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TaskId") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblTaskId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TaskId") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="JobState" HeaderText="State" SortExpression="JobState" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskId" HeaderText="TaskId" SortExpression="TaskId" Visible="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ScheduledDate" HeaderText="Scheduled" SortExpression="ScheduledDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd MMM HH:mm}" Visible="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDate" HeaderText="Started" SortExpression="StartDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd MMM HH:mm}" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EndDate" HeaderText="Ended" SortExpression="EndDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd MMM HH:mm}" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="JobStatusId" HeaderText="JobStatusId" SortExpression="JobStatusId" Visible="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="JobTypeId" HeaderText="JobTypeId" SortExpression="JobTypeId" Visible="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskCount" HeaderText="Tasks" SortExpression="TaskCount" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SuccessCount" HeaderText="Success" SortExpression="SuccessCount" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ErrorCount" HeaderText="Errors" SortExpression="ErrorCount" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="JobTypeId1" HeaderText="JobTypeId1" SortExpression="JobTypeId1" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Jobtype" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Jobtype" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="JobStateId" HeaderText="JobStateId" SortExpression="JobStateId" Visible="False" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="GridPager" />
                    <RowStyle ForeColor="#333333" BackColor="#F7F6F3" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

And the C# code:

```
        protected void grdJobs_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (e.CommandName)
            {
                case "Select":

                    var jobId = (Label)grdJobs.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("lblJobId");
                    var taskId = (Label)grdJobs.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("lblTaskId");
                    if (jobId != null && taskId != null)
                    {
                        CurrentId.Value = jobId.Text;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jobId.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(taskId.Text))
                        {
                            RefreshData(int.Parse(jobId.Text), int.Parse(taskId.Text));
                        }

                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SiteToolKit.Tools.ExceptionHandler(ex, "grdJobs_RowCommand", lblError);
        }
    }
    protected void grdJobs_GridPaging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {

        grdJobs.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        grdJobs.DataBind();

    }

    protected void grdJobs_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        string ColumnToSort = e.SortExpression;

        if (CurrentSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            CurrentSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
            SortGridView(ColumnToSort, DESCENDING);
        }
        else
        {
            CurrentSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
            SortGridView(ColumnToSort, ASCENDING);
        }
    }

    public SortDirection CurrentSortDirection
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
            {
                ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
            }
            return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = value;
        }
    }

    private void SortGridView(string sortExpression, string direction)
    {
        //  You can cache the DataTable for improving performance  
        dynamic dt = ViewState["Paging"];
        DataTable dtsort = dt;
        DataView dv = new DataView(dtsort);
        dv.Sort = sortExpression + direction;

        grdJobs.DataSource = dv;
        grdJobs.DataBind();
    }
```

My View looks like: 
[image: JobHistory View]

I wonder how to tackle this issue with both working?

As seen in this image, I need to have a `OnRowCommand` and also want to have pagination in this. Is there any possibilities to handle both of these event at a time?

Thanks

Comment: I dont understand the question correctly. As you are already handling the "Select" in the OnRowComand what harm it is creating when pagination happens?

Comment: As you could see the method Select, It handles to load the second grid accordingly to the parent id.  For example, You could see the first row is selected in the first grid and the second grid is shown accordingly the id of the first grid. I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: I get it...You are saying the "RowCommand" executed first and that should not harm the pagination as you are only handling the "Select" command there. Are you saying pagination method never hit the breakpoint?

Comment: Yes, every time I click on the number from the pagination it never hit to the `grdJobs_GridPaging`. It will always go to the rowCommand method and handle select command which occur an error.

Comment: You could check in the OnRowCommand by placing breakpoint. When you do pagination the command name(e.CommandName == "Page") should be page!

Comment: I could not change e.CommandName, It will always show as a Select, Can you please elaborate on how to change  the commandName.

Comment: May be yhe problem is other place .. add your code for rowdtataboind and page load!